# Prometheus 1.8/2.2.1 scrape gives "no token" error - promtool shows only a few warnings

Tags: prometheus

I'm out of options here. I have a the Confluence Prometheus exporter installed, which worked for months. Now while migrating to Prometheus 2.x i noticed it failing (but it also does this now on 1.8, so it's not due to the migration). I'm unaware of any changes on the target system.

Things I checked so far:

- The scrape URL (https) is correct and can be retrieved
- promtool check metrics gives some warning but no error
  (confluence_cluster_panic_count counter metrics should have "_total" suffix)
- response doesn't have a BOM
- other https targets are scraped without an issue
- double checked config
- enabled --log.level=debug, but no additional output

How can I get more information to debug? This is what I get in prometheus logfile:

```
May  8 10:38:59 prometheus-2-test prometheus[3404]: level=warn ts=2018-05-08T10:38:59.038653969Z caller=scrape.go:697 component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=confluence-prod target="https://myserver:443/plugins/servlet/prometheus/metrics?token=feakingSecurityToken" msg="append failed" err="no token found"
```

I think the corresponding lines in scarpe.go are:

```
        // A failed scrape is the same as an empty scrape,
    // we still call sl.append to trigger stale markers.
    total, added, appErr := sl.append(b, start)
    if appErr != nil {
        level.Warn(sl.l).Log("msg", "append failed", "err", appErr)
        // The append failed, probably due to a parse error or sample limit.
        // Call sl.append again with an empty scrape to trigger stale markers.
        if _, _, err := sl.append([]byte{}, start); err != nil {
            level.Warn(sl.l).Log("msg", "append failed", "err", err)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisited this after an upgrade to a newer exporter version. Still the same "no token" error on a perfectly fine scrape target URL.

The URL is behind an Apache 2.4 reverse proxy which does the SSL termination (Confluence is hosting the endpoint with a Tomcat). The Apache has a typical HTTPS setup (`RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent] and on 443 vhost RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"`).

We noticed when temporarily removing the HTTPS redirect in Apache and use the HTTP scheme Prometheus scraped the target.

**The solution we found in the end was keeping the scrape URL in Prometheus as HTTP and let the Apache do the redirect to HTTPS.**